# When I refresh my page Firebase authData becomes null

Tags: angularjs, firebasesimplelogin, firebase-authentication

```
var user = null;    

this.showLoginDialogGoogle  = function(){

        var ref = new Firebase("https://googlelogin1.firebaseio.com");
        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
                user = authData;
                This.goToPage('/profile');
                $rootScope.flag=true;
                $rootScope.$digest();
            }
        });
    };
```

I have authenticated the user with firebase google authentication. The problem is when I refresh my page, my session expires and `authData` becomes `null`. What can I do so that after refreshing the page my `authData` remains with the data it got at the time of authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [monitor authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication):

```
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
});
```

Note that you're not using the AngularFire authentication wrappers. While your approach will authenticate the user, you will have to notify Angular of the updated scope yourself (see `$timeout()`). If you'd rather not do that yourself, look at AngularFire's auth wrappers, specifically [`$onAuth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-auth-state)